# Local version of code works, but breaks when pushing to heroku - multer gcs

Tags: node.js, heroku, grpc, yarnpkg

I have a form in which I submit images and they get uploaded to Firebase. I built the project locally, but when I push it to Heroku it breaks.

Express:

```
var gcs = require( 'multer-gcs' );
var storage = gcs({
    filename    : function( req, file, cb ) {
      cb( null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() );
    },
    bucket      : 'mybucket.appspot.com', // Required : bucket name to upload 
    projectId      : 'mybucket', // Required : Google project ID 
    keyFilename : './mybucket-firebase-adminsdk-4oyba-xee555bbgr.json', // Required : JSON credentials file for Google Cloud Storage 
    acl : 'publicread' // Optional : Defaults to private 
});

const multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({storage: storage});

app.post('/sell', upload.any(), homeController.postSellPage);
```

First Error Code (From `Heroku Logs`):

```
Error: Cannot find module 'multer-gcs'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:22:11)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

So then I ran the following in order to update my `package.json`: `npm install multer-gcs --save`, and it installed, while giving me this message:

```
deprecated gcloud@0.36.0: gcloud has been renamed to google-cloud. To get new features and bug fixes, you must use the new package.
```

I don't know what to do with that message, so I didn't do anything, except re-push to heroku, after committing the new `package.json`. I got the following issue:

```
Build failed

Outdated Yarn lockfile

Your application contains a Yarn lockfile (yarn.lock) which does not
match the dependencies in package.json. This can happen if you use npm
to install or update a dependency instead of Yarn.

Please run the following command in your application directory and check
in the new yarn.lock file:

$ yarn install
$ git add yarn.lock
$ git commit -m "Updated Yarn lockfile"
$ git push heroku master

https://kb.heroku.com/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-an-outdated-yarn-lockfile
```

So I then ran `yarn install`, but got

```
The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "6.9.5".
Found incompatible module
Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

So I looked and in package.json I have the following, which includes the node `6.9.5`, so I think I'm ok in that regard.

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.5",
    "npm": "4.6.1",
    "yarn": "1.3.2"
  },
```

I then ran `yarn install --ignore-engines`, based on a posting about this same issue. That gave me the following:

```
/Users/user/path/node_modules/gcloud/node_modules/grpc: Command failed.
Exit code: 127
Command: ./node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
```

I tried running this command `npm install --unsafe-perm`, based on another posting, but again this issue with `grpc`.

I would love any help that is out there about how I might go about getting heroku to accept/run the build, as I'm stumped on this one. Please let me know if any clarification is needed.

As requested, the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "App Name",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "Amazing Application",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.5",
    "npm": "4.6.1",
    "yarn": "1.3.2"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/amazing_app.git"
  },
  "author": "Example",
  "license": "Example",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec",
    "postinstall": "npm rebuild node-sass"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.46.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.7",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "cheerio": "^0.22.0",
    "clockwork": "^0.1.4",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.3.2",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "errorhandler": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-flash": "^0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.14.2",
    "express-status-monitor": "^0.1.5",
    "express-validator": "^3.1.2",
    "fbgraph": "^1.3.0",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^4.2.1",
    "github": "^9.2.0",
    "grpc": "1.3.8",
    "instagram-node": "^0.5.8",
    "lastfm": "^0.9.2",
    "lob": "^3.9.0",
    "lusca": "^1.4.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.6",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "multer-gcs": "^1.0.2",
    "node-base64-image": "^1.0.3",
    "node-foursquare": "^0.3.0",
    "node-linkedin": "^0.5.4",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^0.11.0",
    "nodemailer": "^3.1.7",
    "passport": "0.3.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport-github": "^1.1.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-instagram": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-linkedin-oauth2": "^1.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-oauth": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-openid": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-twitter": "^1.0.4",
    "paypal-rest-sdk": "^1.7.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta6",
    "request": "^2.78.0",
    "stripe": "^4.12.0",
    "tumblr.js": "^1.1.1",
    "twilio": "^3.3.1-edge",
    "twit": "^2.2.5",
    "validator": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^3.9.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.1.0",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "airbnb-base",
    "rules": {
      "comma-dangle": 0,
      "consistent-return": 0,
      "no-param-reassign": 0,
      "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
      "no-shadow": 0,
      "no-console": 0,
      "no-plusplus": 0
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE:**It only breaks when I uncomment the stuff under `Express` (shown above).

**UPDATE:**

**The application will successfully post to Heroku when I use AWS with Multer `var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');var s3 = new aws.S3({});` so it MUST be something with GCS and its dependencies**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps

1. Remove the `yarn.lock` file
2. Add a new `Aptfile`, with below content

   ```
   gcc
   build-essential
   ```
3. Add the `apt` buildpack using below command

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
   ```

Once you have done that, make a push again to heroku and now it should work

[image: Heroku works]

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but do you *NEED* to include the `yarn.lock` file? I know it keeps your dependencies locked at the exact versions you used, but you should be fine without it in most instances?

If you were to `git rm yarn.lock` heroku may like you better, in theory.

Also possible is that something in your node_modules is somehow broken (I'm not 100% sure how this happens exactly) or your `yarn.lock` has something wrong. You might try to `rm` both of those and re-run `yarn install`

Comment: So just remove yarn completely?

Comment: If I remove yarn I get an error about grpc...`Cannot find module`

Comment: Can you include your `package.json` file (or at least the dependencies)?

Comment: Edited my answer to also suggest possibly `rm -r node_modules yarn.lock` and re-run yarn install. Sometimes stuff gets weirdly corrupted.

Comment: I just added it!

Comment: This didn't fix the problem